# How to distinguish between two web clients on the same IP

Tags: node.js, http, server, http-headers, xmlhttprequest

I need to create a temporary working space for each client that is not logged in (a folder on the server) before the client logs in.

I am currently using the ip address to create an object but there can be more than one client with the same ip if they come from the same client LAN.

These clients will end up at the same folder and their work will be commingled.

How do i differentiate for these clients?

I am working with MEAN stack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have clients that can log in, create the folder for those users based on their unique identifier (like their database id) when the user information is created. When they log in, you will know what folder to use.

You could use cookies or some browser session to assign unique identifiers (uuids?) to users as they hit your site. You could use [browser-fingerprint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browser-fingerprint) and/or [uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) to assign unique values.